# Get row with max timestamp value before a date in partitioned table without scanning all partitions

Tags: database, postgresql, partitioning, database-partitioning

I've created a partitioned table to store measurement data associated with a timestamp and then ranged partitions for each year. I also created an index on the field with the timestamp.

```
CREATE TABLE vision.measure_value_p (
    id_measure_channel integer NOT NULL,
    module_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    value_unit numeric(16,4)
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE (module_date);

CREATE TABLE vision.measure_value_2022 PARTITION OF vision.measure_value_p FOR VALUES FROM ('2022-01-01') TO ('2023-01-01');
CREATE TABLE vision.measure_value_2021 PARTITION OF vision.measure_value_p FOR VALUES FROM ('2021-01-01') TO ('2022-01-01');
...

CREATE INDEX measure_value_idx_p ON vision.measure_value_p USING btree (module_date);
```

I'm trying to get the row with the max timestamp before a date.

I tried to use the following request:

```
SELECT * FROM vision.measure_value_p WHERE module_date < '2021-10-01' ORDER BY module_date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

It perfectly works as I got the right result. But as I looked trough the result of `EXPLAIN` on this request it appears PostgreSQL is also scanning all the partitions until 2021 included even if something was found in 2021 table. 2022 was not scanned as expected.
Below the plan given by `EXPLAIN` :

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Limit",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Async Capable": false,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Gather Merge",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Async Capable": false,
          "Workers Planned": 2,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Sort",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Sort Key": ["measure_value_p.module_date DESC"],
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Append",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Parallel Aware": true,
                  "Async Capable": false,
                  "Subplans Removed": 0,
                  "Plans": [
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Member",
                      "Parallel Aware": true,
                      "Async Capable": false,
                      "Relation Name": "measure_value_2020",
                      "Alias": "measure_value_p_3",
                      "Filter": "(module_date < '2021-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)"
                    },
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Member",
                      "Parallel Aware": true,
                      "Async Capable": false,
                      "Relation Name": "measure_value_2021",
                      "Alias": "measure_value_p_4",
                      "Filter": "(module_date < '2021-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)"
                    },
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Member",
                      "Parallel Aware": true,
                      "Async Capable": false,
                      "Relation Name": "measure_value_2019",
                      "Alias": "measure_value_p_2",
                      "Filter": "(module_date < '2021-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)"
                    },
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Member",
                      "Parallel Aware": true,
                      "Async Capable": false,
                      "Relation Name": "measure_value_2018",
                      "Alias": "measure_value_p_1",
                      "Filter": "(module_date < '2021-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)"
                    },
                    {
                      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
                      "Parent Relationship": "Member",
                      "Parallel Aware": true,
                      "Async Capable": false,
                      "Relation Name": "measure_value_default",
                      "Alias": "measure_value_p_5",
                      "Filter": "(module_date < '2021-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I tried with creating an `INDEX` like following but it didn't change anything.

```
CREATE INDEX measure_value_idx_p ON vision.measure_value_p USING btree (module_date DESC LAST NULLS);
```

I thought there would be a way to make the request starts from 2021 and then stops if it finds some result but I found nothing for now.

Is there a way to make the request be more effective ?

Comment: Your select statement is invalid.  Once I make the obvious correction, it then works for me.  What version are you using?  Please show the plan, maybe you are misinterpreting it.

Comment: Hello,
Sorry for the mistake in the select statement. I made the correction and added the plan given by EXPLAIN in the main question.

Comment: For me, it works the way you want, since v12.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answer. I'm using v14.5 so it should be OK.
So maybe am I misunderstanding the plan given by EXPLAIN. Is the plan I posted similar to what you have ?